# IP lookup heading almost overlapping first entry

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) The initial issue has been fixed. There are some other issues as a consequence of new design, but those have to wait a little.

---

I don't quite remember what it was like pre-design, but it now looks like the heading is nearly overlapping with the first entry on the page.  It's just a little hard to tell with that entry scribbled out.  Perhaps there doesn't need to be much white underneath the horizontal line.

[image]

Comment: It looks like another manifestation of [this bug](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6190/9357).

Comment: Jamal, can you confirm it is fine now? otherwise, can you provide more details?

Comment: @Paweł: It has been updated, except now, [the name is misaligned](http://i.imgur.com/Cb9QgpG.jpg).

Comment: @Jamal thanks for reporting this. i see it's misaligned on my machine as well. however this has to wait a little. it's network-wise issue but we will do something about this at some point. i hope it's still useable & readable in this form.

Comment: Yeah, it's still okay.  Thanks!